# T-SQL Can't get CASE statement to choose just one alternative

Tags: sql, t-sql, case

In our system each customer has a salutation (0) and some also have another additional salutation (22). What I need to do is get those that don't have a 22 to default to 0 instead. I'm trying to accomplish this using a case statement:

```
select distinct a.customer_no,
case when b.sal_code = '22' then '22' 
    when b.sal_code <> '22' then '0'
    else '0'
end as salutation_no
from t_customer a
    join t_sal b
on a.customer_no = b.customer_no    
where a.customer_no in (1734379, 120706)
```

However instead of getting 22 for customers with 22s and 0s for those that don't, I get a 0 on all customers and an additional 22 for those who also have that:

```
customer_no salutation_no
120706       0
120706       22
1734379      0
```

Comment: I think the not equals operator for T-SQL is "!=" see this [post](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190296.aspx)

Comment: incorrect <> is fine in TSQL but you can also use != (I prefer <>)

Comment: `DISTINCT` is not just for one column, it works across all selected columns.  `SELECT DISTINCT a, b` gives two rows if there are two `a` values with different `b` values.  See @Szymon's solution, it should work well for you.

Answer (score 3):

You get double records as there are 2 salutations for some customers and the result of join is those double records.

You can get one records by using this query. It uses `max` function since you want 22 to override 0.

```
select a.customer_no,
    max(sal_code) as salutation_no
from t_customer a
    join t_sal b
on a.customer_no = b.customer_no    
where a.customer_no in (1734379, 120706)
group by a.customer_no
```

Answer (score 1):

Join to salutation only when it is type `'22'`, all others will now have `null` for `sal_code`. Use `coalesce` to default `null` to `'0'`.

```
select C.customer_no
    , coalesce(S.sal_code, '0') as salutation_no
from t_customer C
left join t_sal S
    on S.customer_no = C.customer_no
    and S.sal_code = '22'
where S.customer_no in (1734379, 120706)
```

1. Not clear on the data model, if you'll need `distinct` or not.
2. This will include `t_customer` rows with no row in `t_sal` that would be filtered out in your query. Without knowing the data, I am not 100% sure this is an appropriate solution.

Answer (score 0):

Another way of avoiding duplications is to use `union all`:

```
select s.customer_no, '22' as sal_code
from t_sal s
where s.sal_code = '22'
union all
select c.customer_no, '0'
from t_customer c
where not exists (select 1 from t_sal s where s.customer_no = c.customer_no and s.sal_code = '22');
```

This should be faster than any query that uses `group by` or `select distinct`.